# Azure Mobile App offline sync: Working with IMobileServiceSyncTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I am building a UWP app which uses SQLite db to store data locally and `Azure Mobile App Backend` to enable offline sync capability.
I have followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data) to enable offline sync in my app. 
Now I want to execute a query which would return me number of rows in a table depending upon certain condition
Normally, I could use `LINQ` to easily do something like this

```
todoTable.Where(item => item.Completed == true).Count()
```

But while working with `IMobileServiceSyncTable` I am not getting `LINQ` methods or extensions like `Count`, `Distinct`, `FirstOrDefault` etc. All I get is the set of methods/properties provided by `IMobileServiceSyncTable`.

[image]

Am I missing something here, if not can someone please guide me on how this can be achieved.

Following is the code snippet. I am trying to get the count of images where the image title matches "sometext":

```
IMobileServiceSyncTable<Image> entitySyncTable = AzureBackendService.MobileServiceClient.GetSyncTable<Image>();
int count = entitySyncTable.Where(i => i.Title.Contains("sometext")).Count();
```

However I get following error on `Count()`:

> 'IMobileServiceTableQuery' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count' accepting a first argument of type 'IMobileServiceTableQuery' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you add the code snippet where you make use of the sync table and create the query? thanks

Comment: @woelliJ added the code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `IMobileServiceSyncTable` and the `IMobileServiceTableQuery` created from it don't support LINQ extensions. The main functionality is in the `Where` and the `ToListAsync`.

If you want LINQ queries you can try to use the `IMobileServiceTableQuery<T>.Query` property which exposes the `IQueryable<T>` interface. I haven't tried that personally and am not sure whether you can call `FirstOrDefault` or `ToList` directly on that queryable or you need to go back to the `IMobileServiceTableQuery<T>`

The scenarios it seems it is designed for are:

- user specific items of any kind where the user items are already filtered at the server to only return the user's items.
- transient data for all users that can is updated regularly and eventually will lose value and can be purged

If the app requires to have a lot of server data locally and needs to do a lot of local filtering it might be the wrong technology / design.

Comment: I have tried following code: `IMobileServiceTableQuery<Image> query = entitySyncTable.CreateQuery().Where(i => i.Title.Contains("sometext")).Count();` , if this is what you are referring to it also has the same issue as the `Query` does not expose `LINQ`

Comment: after `CreateQuery()` you can get the `Query` Property and try LINQ on there. I'm not sure it will work though. If your current `Where` clause doesn't work it's likely, because the `string.Contains` is not implemented with the SQLite storage

Comment: it probably isn't supported then. if it's not too much data you could just materialize the results with `ToListAsync` and count them